# Creating a page to dynamically allow user to create forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms, clone, customization

So we've been struggling with a project the past few weeks, and the simple idea is to create a website for our school to use to send and receive forms. At this point  we are trying to create the page where admins can dynamically create forms, akin to Google Forms. Right now our HTML looks like so:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Create Form</TITLE>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="createform.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form method="POST">
<div id="dynamicInput">
<label for="fieldName">Name this field</label>
<input type="text" name="fieldName">
<br><br>

<SELECT name="element">
<OPTION value="text">Textbox</OPTION>
<OPTION value="radio">Radio</OPTION>
<OPTION value= "textarea">Text Area</option>
<OPTION value = "checkbox">Check Box</option>
</SELECT>

<input type="button" value="Add an option" onClick="addAllInputs('dynamicInput', document.forms[0].element.value);">
</div>


<br><br><br>

<input type = "button" value="Add another field" onClick = "addSec();">
<br><br>
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Our JavaScript:

```
var counterText = 0;

var counterRadioButton = 0;

var counterCheckBox = 0;

var counterTextArea = 0;

var counter = 0;
function addAllInputs(divName, inputType){

     var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

     switch(inputType) {

          case 'text':

               newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " +(counterText+1)+" <input type='text' name='myInputs[]'><br>";

               counterText++;

               break;

          case 'radio':

               newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " +(counterRadioButton+1)+" <input type='radio' name='myRadioButtons[]'>";

               counterRadioButton++;

               break;

          case 'checkbox':

               newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry "+(counterCheckBox+1)+" <input type='checkbox' name='myCheckBoxes[]'>";

               counterCheckBox++;

               break;

          case 'textarea':

           newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry "+(counterTextArea+1)+" <textarea name='myTextAreas[]'>type here...</textarea>";

               counterTextArea++;

               break;
          }

     document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
function addSec(){
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

    var div = document.getElementById('dynamicInput').innerHTML;
    newdiv.innerHTML = document.getElementById('dynamicInput');
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);

}
```

We've tried many different iterations of the AddSec function, which is meant to duplicate the HTML div which makes a form field. We have gotten it to duplicate the div, however it comes with all of the "options" like checkboxes and text fields that we have added to the original field, and it cannot be modified in any way. Any advice on this would be appreciated, and we would prefer pure JavaScript methods but jQuery would be okay if we can get it working.

So far I have tested using the .clone function to clone the dynamicInput div, and have also tried adding the new divs into an array but nothing about the program was functioning.

Comment: So what’s the desired result? Why can’t the duplicated `<div>` be modified?

Comment: The intended result is for the div template to be the same, but allow for more entry options to be added to that part of the form. So for example, I could have the first field be for Name, and just have a text box for name. Then I would want to make a new field, this one with four checkboxes and it is called Undergraduate Level. The problem right now is with the .clone method it will duplicate the original field with whatever options it had, and no new options can be added to the new fields. With the .innerHTML method I have now, nothing happens at all.

Comment: Are you using the deep clone argument in `.clone`? Why are you assigning an element to `.innerHTML`? Only text can be assigned to it. Did you mean `newdiv.innerHTML = div;`?

Comment: Yes, that is more what I meant. And by deep clone, I assume that means setting it as true? If so, yes, and I ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

Added a [**Plunk**](https://embed.plnkr.co/iF48q3kXmQsebel1T2Ha/)

---

This Demo makes `<input type='text'>`, `<textarea>`, `<input type='checkbox'>`, groups of `<input type='radio'>` and `<select>`. It also creates extra `<fieldset>` as well. Each form control has a unique #id and matching `[name]` and each radio button has a unique id but a common `[name]` for each group.

I didn't make `<label>` an option, I figure if you follow the pattern, you should be able to add it in as a simple string. The following references are to what was used:

[**insertAdjacentHTML()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

[**Template Literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

[**Event Delegation**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

[**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)

```js
var formA = document.forms[0];
var formB = document.forms[1];
var ui = formA.elements;
var base = formB.elements;

formA.addEventListener('change', selectTag);
formA.addEventListener('click', addFieldset);

function selectTag(e) {
  var rad = `s${document.querySelector('.rad:checked').value}`;
  var fst = base[rad];
  var qty;
  var ask;
  var idx = -1;
  if (e.target.id === "sel") {
    idx = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
  }
  switch (idx) {
    case 0:
      var ID0 = Math.round(new Date().valueOf() / 3000000 + performance.now());
      var input = `<input id="t${ID0}" name="t${ID0} type="text">`;
      fst.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', input);
      break;
    case 1:
      var ID1 = Math.round(new Date().valueOf() / 3000000 + performance.now());
      var textArea = `<textarea id="ta${ID1}" name="ta${ID1}"></textarea>`;
      fst.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', textArea);
      break;
    case 2:
      var ID2 = Math.round(new Date().valueOf() / 3000000 + performance.now());
      var check = `<input id="ch${ID2}" name="ch${ID2}" type='checkbox' value=''>`;
      fst.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', check);
      break;
    case 3:
      var ID3 = Math.round(new Date().valueOf() / 3000000 + performance.now());
      ask = prompt('Enter the number of radio buttons needed');
      var rads = [];
      qty = parseInt(ask, 10);
      var name = ID3 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 10;
      for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
        var radio = `<input id="r${ID3+i}" name="r${name}" type='checkbox' value=''>`;
        rads.push(radio);
        fst.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', radio);
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      var ID4 = Math.round(new Date().valueOf() / 3000000 + performance.now());
      var select = `<select id="s${ID4}" name="s${ID4}"></select>`;
      ask = prompt('Enter the number of options needed');
      qty = parseInt(ask, 10);
      fst.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', select);
      var sel = document.getElementById('s' + ID4);
      for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        sel.add(opt);
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}


function addFieldset(e) {
  if (e.target.id === 'addSet') {
    var sets = formB.querySelectorAll('fieldset').length;
    var fs = `
    <fieldset id='s${sets}'>
      <legend>${sets}</legend>
    </fieldset>`;
    formB.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', fs);
    var rad = `
    <input id='r${sets}' name='rad' class='rad' type='radio' value='${sets}'>
    <label for='r${sets}'>${sets}</label>`;
    ui.addSet.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', rad);
  }
}
```

```html
<form id='ui'>

  <fieldset id='set'>
    <legend>Create Form</legend>
    <select id='sel'>
      <option>Pick a Field</option>
      <option value='0'>Text Box</option>
      <option value='1'>Text Area</option>
      <option value='2'>Checkbox</option>
      <option value='3'>Radio Group</option>
      <option value='4'>Select</option>
    </select>
    <input id='r0' name='rad' class='rad' type='radio' value='0' checked>
    <label for='r0'>0</label>
    <input id='r1' name='rad' class='rad' type='radio' value='1'>
    <label for='r1'>1</label>
    <input id='r2' name='rad' class='rad' type='radio' value='2'>
    <label for='r2'>2</label>
    <input id='r3' name='rad' class='rad' type='radio' value='3'>
    <label for='r3'>3</label>
    <button id='addSet' type='button'>Add Fieldset</button>
  </fieldset>

</form>

<form id='base'>
  <fieldset id='s0'>
    <legend>0</legend>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id='s1'>
    <legend>1</legend>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id='s2'>
    <legend>2</legend>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id='s3'>
    <legend>3</legend>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: The code is working here on StackOverflow but upon adding it to my project the page appears like it should but none of the javascript is working. The jQuery code is greyed out in Notepad++, and so I assumed that meant I needed to add jQuery into the library for the file to access, which I thought I had done but nothing seems to have changed. Is there a way to do the same thing without jQuery or a guide on how to properly add it to the project for use?

Comment: This really helped create a basis for what we are going for. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var counterText = 0;

var counterRadioButton = 0;

var counterCheckBox = 0;

var counterTextArea = 0;

var counter = 0;
function addAllInputs(divName, inputType){

     var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

     switch(inputType) {

          case 'text':

               newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " +(counterText+1)+" <input type='text' name='myInputs[]'><br>";

               counterText++;

               break;

          case 'radio':

               newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " +(counterRadioButton+1)+" <input type='radio' name='myRadioButtons[]'>";

               counterRadioButton++;

               break;

          case 'checkbox':

               newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry "+(counterCheckBox+1)+" <input type='checkbox' name='myCheckBoxes[]'>";

               counterCheckBox++;

               break;

          case 'textarea':

           newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry "+(counterTextArea+1)+" <textarea name='myTextAreas[]'>type here...</textarea>";

               counterTextArea++;

               break;
          }

     document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
function addSec(){
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

    var div = document.getElementById('dynamicInput').innerHTML;
    newdiv.innerHTML = document.getElementById('dynamicInput').innerHTML;
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);

}
```

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Create Form</TITLE>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="createform.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form method="POST">
<div id="dynamicInput">
<label for="fieldName">Name this field</label>
<input type="text" name="fieldName">
<br><br>

<SELECT name="element">
<OPTION value="text">Textbox</OPTION>
<OPTION value="radio">Radio</OPTION>
<OPTION value= "textarea">Text Area</option>
<OPTION value = "checkbox">Check Box</option>
</SELECT>

<input type="button" value="Add an option" onClick="addAllInputs('dynamicInput', document.forms[0].element.value);">
</div>


<br><br><br>

<input type = "button" value="Add another field" onClick = "addSec();">
<br><br>
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

you've missed an innerHTML.

Comment: This allowed the div to be cloned, but the problem is still there where the options added to the original field are cloned too, and attempts to add new options to the new fields just adds them to the original. My theory is I need to create some kind of new id for every new div created, and I need to somehow keep the original field's options from being copied too.

Comment: So you want the generated form with the initial state or new state?

Comment: A new state, or blank, so that an admin can customize options to each one separately.